# A non-numeric value encountered laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

i am passing values to print pdf in laravel controller . In local machine it works perfectly, but in live server it shows the "A non-numeric value encountered" error.

I using barrvdh dom pdf to print pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue when running Dompdf versions < 0.8.0 on a system that uses PHP 7.1 or greater. Most of the issues non-numeric errors were cleared up in 0.8.0. A few more were cleaned up for 0.8.1 (not yet released as of this posting).

Make sure you're using Laravel-Dompdf version 0.8.0 or higher ([releases](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/releases)).

Comment: Could this work for Laravel 4 users? The website https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4 says to use "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*" for Laravel 4  : (

Comment: I'm not sure about that since I'm not a laravel user but it doesn't look like it. The .4 branch hasn't been updated in quite a while. Additionally, .4 is based an older version of dompdf, so you couldn't even use a newer version of dompdf that does not have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed by following solution into "cellmap.cls.php" on line 436

```
/**Old Code:**/

// Determine where this cell is going
$colspan = $node->getAttribute("colspan");
$rowspan = $node->getAttribute("rowspan");

if ( !$colspan ) {
   $colspan = 1;
   $node->setAttribute("colspan",1);
}

if ( !$rowspan ) {
    $rowspan = 1;
    $node->setAttribute("rowspan",1);
}

/**New Code:**/

if(method_exists($node,'getAttribute')){
    // Determine where this cell is going
    $colspan = $node->getAttribute("colspan");
    $rowspan = $node->getAttribute("rowspan");

    if ( !$colspan ) {
       $colspan = 1;
       $node->setAttribute("colspan",1);
    }

    if ( !$rowspan ) {
        $rowspan = 1;
        $node->setAttribute("rowspan",1);
    }
}
```